# Removing code reviewer's -2 on Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Is there a way to remove -2 on a particular code review on Gerrit?  One of our dev is on vacation, and his -2 is currently holding the CR for submission even though we have a +2 from other dev.

Do we have to run this on gsql?

Comment: Moving it to ServerFault

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove him as a reviewer, can't you?  You might need to be an admin.  Alternately, just abandon the commit and resubmit your patch with a different Change-Id.

Comment: Already removed, but his -2 persist.  I was wondering if I need to run gsql into the DB and remove it that way.

Comment: Hm - I thought that would work.  I seem to remember doing it here once, but I am an admin, so I might have superpowers.  Good luck!